# In my iframe i want to incule a specific js file with Ext.ui.iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs

I create an iframe using Ext.ui.iframe (ExtJs) and i want to load a specific file in this iframe exampte test.js
how i can load this specific file in my iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet:-

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    requires: ['Ext.ux.IFrame'],
    launch: function () {

        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'uxiframe',
                closable: true,
                title: 'Preview JS',
                src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

Please have a look on given fiddle and let me know.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2c0h

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18538638)

Comment: Thanks for the review/suggestion, I have added code snippet too.

Comment: I want to load the js file in the head of the iframe, so the result will be like this :  
<iframe>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/colorpick/Button.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
</iframe>